# Interpreting Exchange message tracking log events for unreceived emails

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2010

I'm working on a new Exchange 2010 server that may be having issues sending emails out to a particular ISP.  I have verified it is not on any blacklists, no bounce messages are ever received, and the recipients claim the emails are not getting junked.

I found the SEND events for several of these emails via the `get-messagetrackinglog` command.  In all cases, the `RecipientStatus` is `{250 ok}`.  Can I interpret this to mean that the email was accepted by their server?  I realize that this does not guarantee delivery but I just want to verify that it's not being rejected and that, if something is happening to the emails, that it is happening after it is no longer "in our hands".

If this is not a good indicator of this, for what should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some form of delivery reports from Outlook Web App.

I'll point you to an Exchange team [blog post](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2009/06/08/451562.aspx) on the subject, which goes into a bit of detail with screenshots and all.

Like you said, it won't tell you if the mail was eventually delivered (for external recipients), but it will tell you that it either handed the message to a remote server for further processing (where it can no longer be tracked by your Exchange Server), or it got bounced.

Comment: I'll investigate that blog post and report back here when I've made progress.  Thank you.

Comment: While I wish they'd better document the message tracking log, which is also used to provide the report of which the blog speaks, at least the human readable report verified my interpretation of the log events.  So this did the trick, plus, as a bonus, this way users can verify the message tracking themselves without having to consult an admin.  Thanks very much.